# Backbone : Make collection from slice of another collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pagination

I'd like to have a paginated view of a collection. I tried using Backbone.Paginator but I just couldn't make it work.

I figured I'd do the pagination myself and I thought it would be a good idea to have my full collection, and then send the view a small collection of the big one, and do this every time someone clicks on 'next'.

I tried doing this but it doesn't work :

```
var purchaseCollection = new purchaseItemCollection({url:endpoints.purchases});

purchaseCollection.fetch();

var purchaseRangeCollection = new Backbone.Collection(purchaseCollection.models),
    purchaseView = new purchaseItemCollectionView({collection:purchaseRangeCollection});
```

My second collection is only made of one model when it should have severals.

I'm wondering if this is even the best way to do it.

Any advice on how to **split a collection into collections**, or how to **do it in another way** would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom object to control a collection representing the list of models currently selected.

For example,

```
var Slicer = function(opts) {
    opts || (opts = {});

    // your big collection
    this.collection = opts.collection || new Backbone.Collection();

    // a collection filled with the currently selected models
    this.sliced = new Backbone.Collection();
};

_.extend(Slicer.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
    // a method to slice the original collection and fill the container
    slice: function(begin, end) {
        var models = this.collection.models.slice(begin, end);
        this.sliced.reset(models);

        // triggers a custom event for convenience
        this.trigger('sliced', this.sliced);
    }
});
```

You would then create an instance of this controller and either listen to the custom event `sliced` on this object or on a `reset` event on the `sliced` collection to update your view:

```
var controller = new Slicer({
    collection: purchaseCollection
});
controller.on('sliced', function(c) {
    console.log('sliced', c.pluck('id'));
});
controller.sliced.on('reset', function(c) {
    console.log('reset', c.pluck('id'));
});
```

And a demo to play with http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/zjgkF/

Note that you also have to take into account the asynchronous nature of `fetch`, you can't immediately work on the models. In this setup, you would do something like

```
var purchaseCollection = new purchaseItemCollection(
    [], // you have to pass an array
    {url:endpoints.purchases} // and then your options
);
purchaseCollection.fetch().then(function() {
    // do what you want
    // for example
    controller.slice(0, 10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `model` of your full collection as another independent collection.
Then after `fetch()`, you will get your collections as the `model` of your full one.

```
var PurchaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Backbone.Collection
})

var purchaseCollection = new PurchaseCollection({url:endpoints.purchases});
purchaseCollection.fetch()

purchaseCollection.each(function (purchaseItem, index) {
    //the purchaseItem is what you want...
    //do anything...
});
```

If you want a [demo, click here](http://jsfiddle.net/edisonator/syM6a/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that collection constructor has two attributes (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor). The first are the models and the second are the options like url etc.